# How grep two digit numeric value from grep command

Tags: regex, shell

I have string line like /Modem/34  now I wanted to extract only 34 ..
How to do that.

Comment: Try this `echo "/Modem/34" | grep -Eo '[0-9]+'`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
grep -Eo '[0-9][0-9]' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract the text after last slash:

```
grep -o '[^/]*$'
```

or

```
awk -F'/' '{print $NF}'
```

### update according to OP's comment:

```
$ sed 's#.*/##;s/ .*//'<<< "a/b/c/this fo ba"
this
```

Comment: I tried above but I wanted number after slash & till space.thats it

Comment: This need to store in one variable

Comment: Extract need to stop when space comes in line & need to store in variable

Comment: @user8032404 see updated answer. if you want it in variable, `VAR=$(sed cmd)`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
A="/Modem/34"
echo ${A##*/}
```

Saving string into a variable named A and then using shell's parameter expansion to get only the 34(because it will remove everything till /).
**EDIT:** Adding variable's value into a variable as per OP's request.

```
A="/Modem/34"
VAR=${A##*/}
echo $VAR
34
```

Comment: In above I wanted to extract 34 & store in variable in shell

Comment: @user8032404: Edited my answer now on same, let me know if this helps you.

Comment: After thiry four there is space